# Combo chart line and bar in SSRS 2008 R2 chart

Tags: charts, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a chart which has 3 series- 2 of them needs to be a bar chart and 1 should be a line chart. I tried the various solutions mentioned online to change the chart type of only the series that needs to be changed. Whenever I do that, all series chart types change to the type I change to. For example- if I have series1, series2 and series3 and I change series3 to Line, all the series change to Line chart.

How should I proceed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have different chart types for a **Category** or **Series** - only the **Values**.

[image]

You can probably emulate what you are trying to do by creating 3 different Values and filtering them with an IIF statement.

```
=IIF(Fields!SeriesType.Value = "Series1", Fields!MyField.Value, NOTHING)
```